# Android MultiThread And Touch

Tags: android, multithreading, touch

I have news Application in main page I set Header For Urgent News But the problem is when I make Thread In main activity when I test The app I got in some times touch problem : no event run when i touch in list View And When I rotate my phone I can never run any event with touch i have to close and run again

**Any Idea For This Problem ..**

> for more Details in some tests i got error tell me  your thread number/id
>   [8 or 254 .etc **its change every test**] for touch thread or same mean I don't remember
>   because error now doesn't appear but I think there is some thing like 
>   Conflict with threads .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like your thread is trying to change something in the User Interface (if I got you right). This is not allowed, as only the UI Thread is allowed to change the UserInterface.

You should do some background reading [Using Threads in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads) and it could be useful to have a look on [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method, which executes a Thread on the UI Thread in order to change something in the UI.

Comment: Thanks 'Till' , I replaced My Thread With Handler And Call It With PostDelay And Now Every Thing , Ok .. Except Rotation still disable touch when rotate so I disable it , but I hope to know what's Problem With rotation .